# A GUI program to add/substract dates in Linux

Tags: gui, time-management

I am looking for a GUI program that runs on Linux and has a feature similar to Microsoft calculator to add/substract days, and compute durations between dates in (days, months, years, etc.).

To get an idea about this feature, it is also similar to [this website](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadd.html).

I am not interested in CLI tools like `date` command , etc.

I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: There's a learning curve, but this still exists: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/the-ultimate-linux-or-unix-desktop-calculator.html If that works for you, I can type up an actual answer. It's not a very steep learning curve, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: Libreoffice can surely do it.

Comment: @KGIII: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried it already but imo, it is a little bit hard to use.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: Could you please elaborate a little bit? do you mean libreoffice calc?

Comment: What you'd be looking for is under Functions > Date & Time, if that helps. It's pretty straightforward from there. Alas, it's the only GUI Linux tool that I know of that does date and time. Poke at it for a half hour and you'll probably have it sorted out well enough for your needs.

Comment: If I have to use to use it all the time, I would write one using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript or using Python.

Comment: I got bored and did some more looking. I found something that's *really* straightforward - except the installation. I can talk you through that, if need be. Check [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/datecalculator/).

Comment: Qalculate! It's great for units too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qalculate, a 'Powerful and easy to use calculator' that you find in all distros (even Windows) has the function you are looking for.
You can check it at: https://qalculate.github.io/
It's great for units too.